# Meaning of Druidic dusk

Tags: meaning, etymology, american-english

I'm struggling with a phrase and need help with that, it's from the book **Born to Run by Christopher McDougall (Random House, 2018)**

> Eric had been fascinated with the Tarahumara since an athlete he’d
>   trained for Leadville returned with amazing stories about fantastic
>   Indians flying through the Druidic dusk in sandals and robes

What does the author means by “Drudic dusk”? I searched a lot about the world Druid and know that it’s a term related to ancient Celtic cultures, but at the end can’t find any meaningful relation between this world and the world dust.

Comment: I'd say that this isn't a standard English expression, though it may be a known term in certain subregisters in history / mythology.

Answer (score 1):

> the Druidic dusk

= The dusk that was typical at the time of the Druids. / Dusk at the time of the Druids. (*With the suggestion that the Druids would have seen such things and found them unremarkable*.)

The expression seems to be poor use of English as Druids are a Celtic phenomenon, whereas the Tarahumara Indians are from northwestern Mexico.